# Django - Checking if objects exists and raising error if it does

Tags: python, django

I need to check if an object exists in a table. If the object doesn't exist I want to save it, if it does exist I want to refresh the page and tell the user that the identifier (quote number) already exists. I have this example code:

```
def some_method(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SomeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid:
            quote = request.POST.get('quote')
            if SomeModel.objects.get(quote_number = quote).exists():
               refresh with error #not sure how to do
            else:
               save object #I can do this part
```

The problem I am running into is that when I check if the object exists (and it does) then the code will raise an error saying the object doesn't exist before it hits the `if`. Which means on the webpage is full of coding information rather than the refresh with a message for the user.

I want to be able to have a little pop up message or something for the user to enter a new quote number rather than having the developer error page show up.

Am I going about this the correct way?

Comment: Does `SomeForm` involve the quote at all? ideally that shouldn't be valid if it really isn't

Comment: @Sayse `SomeForm` is a form for posting information about a quote. It's considered "valid" if all the fields are entered correctly. I need to check before the information is save, if the quote number (which is the unique identifier) has already been put into the table.

Comment: You could use the messages framework for the "showing the error" part. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/messages/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is [`get`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#get) returns an object, but [`exists`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists) only works with querysets. A `Model.DoesNotExist` error will be raised when you use `get` and the object does not exist.

You should use `filter` instead of `get`:

```
qs = SomeModel.objects.filter(quote_number = quote)
if qs.exists():
    ...
else:
    ...
```

Comment: I didn't realize that `.exists()` only works on querysets. I just checked the code and it works perfectly. Thank you for your quick answer!

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib import messages

...

try:
    some_object = SomeModel.objects.get(quote_number=quote)
    message.warning(request, 'some message')
    return HttpResponseRedirect('some-url')
except SomeModel.DoesNotExist:
    some_object = SomeModel.objects.create(quote_number=quote)
    ...
```

And in the template you can display the message just like so:

```
{% if messages %}
    {% for message in messages %}
        {{message}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`get_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create). It returns a tuple with object retrieved (or created) and a boolean value. If boolean value is `True` when it's a new object, and if it's `False` when object already exists and you can throw desired error.